# Setting text of UITextView results in crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, uitextview

I am trying to set the text of `UITextView` which has some illegal characters like "Unicode Character 'OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFC)".
Basically, I have a `UITextView`. Now user taps on it and keyboard comes up. Now I use speech to text from keyboard(also known as dictation). When the dictation is processing(at that time `UITextView` has that special character which corresponds to the default placeholder animation), I try to set the value of text view using:

```
textView.text = @""
```

This creates following crash:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'
```

Stack trace which I got from crashlytics:

```
0    CoreFoundation     __exceptionPreprocess + 130
2    CoreFoundation     -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3    CoreFoundation     mutateError + 222
4    Foundation     -[NSString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:] + 134
5    UIKit      __37-[UITextInputController textInRange:]_block_invoke + 310
6    UIFoundation       -[NSTextStorage coordinateReading:] + 36
7    UIKit      -[UITextInputController textInRange:] + 232
8    UIKit      -[TIDocumentState(UITextInputAdditions) _contextAfterPosition:inDocument:] + 190
9    UIKit      -[TIDocumentState(UITextInputAdditions) initWithDocument:] + 150
10    UIKit     +[TIDocumentState(UITextInputAdditions) documentStateOfDocument:] + 52
11    UIKit     -[UIKeyboardImpl updateForChangedSelectionWithExecutionContext:] + 288
12    UIKit     -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 352
13    UIKit     -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:] + 248
14    UIKit     -[UIKeyboardImpl updateForChangedSelection] + 96
15    UIKit     -[UIKeyboardImpl selectionDidChange:] + 102
16    UIFoundation      -[NSTextStorage coordinateReading:] + 36
17    UIKit     -[UITextInputController _coordinateSelectionChange:] + 100
18    UIKit     -[UITextInputController _setSelectedTextRange:] + 604
19    UIKit     -[UITextView setAttributedText:] + 392
20    UIKit     -[UITextView setText:] + 134
```

I have also created a sample project which demonstrates this problem. You can get this project from: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80141854/TextViewDictationCheck.zip

Exception can be reproduced by following steps:

1. List item
2. Run project in xcode.
3. Click on text view. keyboard comes up.
4. press mic button next to space on keyboard.
5. After sometime(4-5 seconds), press done.
6. Now you will see a spinner moving in textview. Press send while that spinner is moving in textview.
7. You will get exception.

I have found one method of avoiding this crash: 
While setting the text of UITextView, we can use following code:
I have also found one more workaround which we can use while resetting text on UITextView:

```
[self.textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [[self.textView textStorage] length])];
[self.textView insertText:@""];
[self.textView setText:@""];
```

But I am still not getting that why this crash happens if we only use setText: to set the text.

Comment: Can you paste the call stack of the crash here?  It's possible that you are using `replaceCharactersInRange:withString` somewhere with an invalid string.

Comment: I have enabled exception breakpoints and the code is stopping at line with code=> textView.text = @""

Comment: Post the callstack.  It will help quite a lot with this type of error.

Comment: @Putz1103: Added trace in question

Comment: Your `setText` function is going to some weird places...  You must have some delegation going on.  It seems like you are listening for text change and doing something with the changed text.  If you remove that delegation it should not crash right there.

Comment: As @Putz1103 mentioned -- you have some delegation issues going on. Check your Delegate method: "replaceCharactersInRange:withString:".

Comment: Yeah! I have some delegation going on. I will try to remove it and check it again. I will keep this post updated with my progress. Thanks for helping so far :)

Comment: @Putz1103: I created a new project with a single view controller having only UITextView and UIButton. I repeated the procedure and again got the same exception. The stack trace is also exact same as previous(which is already added to the question.). Please note that I do not have any delegates or anything fancy going on in this.

Comment: I have added more information to the question. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 3):

The exception happens in the Foundation code, not your code.  There is a race condition that causes this crash if the string is altered while the dictation is being processed.  It places a placeholder into the string when you touch the microphone button, then replaces it with the text when it's finished processing.  If you alter the string and remove the placeholder, it causes a crash.

The fix is to make sure you don't alter the string while dictation is being processed. You can do this by checking the current input mode primary language.  It's set to `dictation` while dictation is in progress:

```
- (IBAction)sendPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *primaryLanguage = [self.textView textInputMode].primaryLanguage;
    if(![primaryLanguage isEqualToString:@"dictation"])
    {

        // Your original method body:
        NSString *textViewText = self.textView.text;
        textViewText = @"";
        self.textView.text = nil;
        self.textView.text = @"";

    }
```

}

This skips the code to empty the textview if dictation is in progress.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. However, I cannot use deprecated methods. Do you know any way by which we can cancel the dictation in between the processing so that that placeholder animation will be removed?

Comment: I've found the replacement method call for the deprecated one and updated the answer with it.

Comment: I have found one workaround to update text by avoiding this crash. Check my updated question. Also, you said that: "There is a race condition that causes this crash", Can you please provide some reference to apple documentation or something where I can check for it.

Comment: I think your `setSelectedRange`, `insertText` workaround works because it forces the updates to the text to be sequential - I think that selecting the entire string obtains a lock somewhere inside the UIKit code.

Comment: Actually, the weird thing here is that calling only setSelectedRange and insertText work fine when we do not have spinner in the textView but if we have spinner also with some text in the textView, then it does not removes the text and only removes the spinner from textview. Many weird things are happening because of this spinner and on top of that I could not find any documentation on that spinner which comes into textview when we use dictation.